# Block spam SMS based on unique words

Tags: applications, sms, spam, sms-blocking

I have many annoying SMSes with unique words, such as: "For Cancel Enter 12".

I am looking for a way to filter those SMSes based on a phrase.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restrictions on apps only. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: I [created a Q there](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87389) - But No body answer yet.